# C Makefile commands

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I was trying to build a C project which has a rather unfamiliar way to define namespaces, eg. in file root.h

```
#define eval CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(eval)
```

And in the Makefile the following appears (rule for make all):

`gcc -O3 -g  -march=native -mtune=native -Wall -I. -Isubroutines -DKAT -DKATNUM='cat KATNUM' "-DCRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=x" "-D_CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=_##x" -o kat nist/kat_kem.c nist/rng.c benes.c bm.c controlbits.c decrypt.c encrypt.c gf.c operations.c pk_gen.c root.c sk_gen.c synd.c transpose.c util.c  -I${PWD}/subroutines   -L${PWD}/libs/ -lXKCP -lcrypto -ldl`

What do these options do:

```
"-DCRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=x" "-D_CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=_##x"
```

I know that `-DXXX=YYY` is the same as `#define XXX YYY`. Now, why is it in double-quotes? Why it looks like a macro (may be it is)? Lastly, what does `_##x` mean?

Comment: You will have to improve formatting to make your question readable and answerable. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This `root.h:#define eval CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(eval)` is very unclear. It is neither makefile syntax nor C syntax. Do you mean to express that the file named "root.h" contains a single line with a `#define` ? Please provide a more carefully represented [mre] of the different files in your project.

Comment: What is confusing you about the `"-DCRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=x" "-D_CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x)=_##x"`? The meaning of `-D`, the preprocessor syntax and effect of `##` ? Please be more precise about what you want explained. Do you understand the preprocessor effect of `#define CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x) x` and `#define _CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x) _##x`?

Comment: That's probably a terrible user interface, but [concatentaion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Comment: @Yunnosch Edited, hopefully it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

The macro in the header:

```
#define eval CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(eval)
```

Replaces every token `eval` with `CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(eval)`. So if the code contains

```
void eval(char *expr) {
...
```

the preprocessor output - without any other definition - would be

```
void CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(eval)(char *expr) {
...
```

The `-D` parameters effectively add two more definitions:

```
#define DCRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x) x 
#define _CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(x) _##x
```

In our example, the first `define` causes the normal result to be re-written one more time:

```
void eval(char *expr) {
...
```

so we're back where we started. A different definition could be used to change the compiled name of the function. This definition makes the header definition a no-op.

The second macro uses the token concatenation operator `##`.  It adds a prefix underscore `_` to the macro argument. E.g. if the code contained something like:

```
void _CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(foo)(int x) {
```

then the result is

```
void _foo(int x) {
```

At a higher level, these macros allow names of things (in the first case anything named `eval` and in the second, any name at all) to be transformed uniformly throughout the program. This is a fairly standard workaround for name collisions in big C programs.  If you have two source code bases that have both defined the same public function name, macros like this can be used to add a prefix or suffix that changes one or both names in the compiled code without modifying either original code. This is an important capability for long-term configuration management where manually editing externally furnished code bases isn't a serious option.

A wild guess is that this treatment is given to `eval` because the likelihood of some other chunk of C also defining a function named `eval` is extremely high.